# pipenv shell failed creating virtual environment

Tags: pipenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment with the following command:

```
pipenv --three
```

But it doesn't work as the image shows:

[image: My error]

What should I do?

I don't have virtual environment(s), like **venv** or **virtualenv**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question. Please, do not show error messages or code as screenshot, copy/paste them in code blocks in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it in the following way

Uninstall PIP and pipenv, reinstall the version of python3. If not work,  reinstall Python 3.7

```
sudo apt remove pip
sudo apt remove pipenv
sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip
pip3 install pipenv
pipenv shell
```

[Installing pip/setuptools/wheel with Linux Package Managers](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/)